# How are multiple conditional statements evaluated in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I need to evaluate multiple conditional statements, is it faster to use a nested series of `if` statements or to place all conditions within a single `if` statement separated by `and`? For example:

```
x=[True, False, False, True]
y=[0,1,2,3]

for i in list(range(len(x))):
    if x[i] and expensive_computation(y[i]):
        do_something

    if x[i]:
        if expensive_computation(y[i]):
            do_something
```

Will the first conditional statement `if x[i] and expensive_computation(y[i])` check the Boolean value of `expensive_computation(y[i])` if `x[i]` is already False?

Comment: No, `and` short-circuits.

Comment: `and` becomes `if` in the byte code so they are mostly equivalent. Try it boths ways then use `dis.dis()` to check.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and for providing a link to a similar question. I had not heard of the term short-circuiting before, and so I did not discover this question in my search.